# Android Studio Error: VCPU Shutdown request

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, virtual-machine, haxm, vcpu

I,m running Intel Core i3, 4 GB Ram, 32bit, HAXM Version 7.2.0

Android emulator: Nexus 5X API 28

I give the following command in the terminal:

```
E:\Android_SDK\emulator>emulator @Nexus_5X_API_28

HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
VCPU shutdown request (Shows the same about 15 times)
emulator: WARNING: Not saving state: emulator hasn't finished booting.
VCPU shutdown request
```

Tried all the methods but none of them helped.

Answer (score 3):

For me, reinstalling intel haxm and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I had exact the same problem in Windows 10. The only solution I could find was that running emulator in terminal with administrator mode.

Good luck!